# C++ Pointer (Pass By Reference) Question

Tags: c++

A pointer that is passed-in-by-reference. Why? aren't pointers just references anyways? What's really happening to this parameter?

```
void someFunc(MyPtr*& Object)
{

}
```

Comment: "aren't pointers just references anyways?" - there's a slight ambiguity here. In general computer science terms, pointers are a kind of reference. However C++ uses the same word, "reference", to mean a specific language feature. C++ references are also a kind of reference, but they're a *different* kind of reference, and pointers aren't C++ references.

Comment: @ Steve Jessop: +1 similar reasons made me write up  my answer too. Ref Vs Pointer  nice visual doc -> http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/~patrick/csc418/wi2004/notes/PointersVsRef.pdf  just seems it will always cause a great deal of confusion. Similar thing is in C# but lots of poeple don't realize there is even a problem - actually it's even more complex then c++ as far as pass by ref & pass by value goes because it has logic layers on top of C++ concepts. Too bad few people realize C# is actually more complex then C++ when it comes to what is "pointers" (not talking about unsafe code at all here)

Comment: cont. But it's really simple on the other hand, if you think of it like this: when computers store data(a variable for example) the data has only 2 characteristics: (1)an address in memeory & (2)value written at that address. That's any data. Pointers & references and such abstractions introduced for convenience. Any medium that stores data like DVDs for example are the same like a paper book: you have a page where you have a sentence written - its the same really - you have to write the (1)information  (2)somewhere. Dreams on the other hand may be more complex as far as storage goes:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply speaking, it gives you the ability to change the pointer itself: it can be changed to point to another location in the function.
And the change will be reflected outside.

Answer (score 5):

It enable you to:

```
void someFunc(MyPtr*& Object)
{
  //Modify what Object is pointing to
  Object=&old_Object;

  //You can also allocate memory, depending on your requirements
  Object=new MyPtr;

  //Modify the variable Object points to
  *Object=another_object;
}
```

Comment: Don't we have a memory leak in the above situation ?

Comment: @Mahesh No, as long as the caller knows it must delete the new object when it's finished with it

Answer (score 1):

Other's will have to vote to verify this cause I'm a bit rusty on my C++ but I believe the idea here is you'd pass in a pointer by reference, that is instead of creating a new space to store the pointer itself you use a reference to the pointer so if you were to modify the pointer not just the value it would be modified after returning from the function, whereas otherwise all you could do is modify the value at position passed in.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The difference to passing just a pointer is that if the pointer is changed (`Object = x`) then this change will be seen by the calling function. You could achieve the same when you pass `MyPtr** Object` and dereference the pointer `*Object = x;`. With the second approach you could pass NULL to the function. This is not possible for references.

Answer (score 1):

You are not quite right. The pointer *content* is passed by reference but the pointer itself is still passed by value, i.e. reassinging it to some other pointer will not be reflected upon the exit from the method because the pointer will be set to point to the same memory block as before the call. Think of it as a simple int variable. However with &* or ** you can reassign the pointer and that will be visible outside the scope of this method.

Answer (score 1):

> Why?

For the same reason that you would pass in anything else by reference.

> aren't pointers just references anyways?

Dear god, no. Not even remotely the same thing. Look, you can **try** to build a mental model of a reference by **starting with** a pointer, but by the time you've fixed up all the differences, you have a horrible illogical mess.

References are a much simpler and more intuitive concept, and there are only "historical reasons" for trying to understand pointers before them. Modern C++ uses raw pointers only rarely, and treats them as an implementation detail as much as possible.

A reference is another name for an already-existing thing. That's it. When used as a function parameter, they thus allow the called function to refer to the caller's data.

Answer (score 0):

It also means the pointer can be 0 (NULL) which can having meaning to the method.  A reference must always be valid and cannot be made 'nothing'